# Should a doall Clojure function be used with a reduce call?

Tags: clojure, reduce, clojurescript, lazy-sequences, hiccup

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame,
reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic
web app project. I am new to Clojure.

At some point in the codebase there is a big use of `doall` command followed by the use of `reduce` in order to generate hiccup (HTML renderer):

```clj
(doall
   (reduce
      (fn  ...) ...)
   []            ; hiccup-output
  project-variable)
```

I am new to Clojure. But this felt weird to me considering [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall):

> When lazy sequences are produced via functions that have side
> effects, any effects other than those needed to produce the first
> element in the seq do not occur until the seq is consumed. doall can
> be used to force any effects. Walks through the successive nexts of
> the seq, retains the head and returns it, thus causing the entire
> seq to reside in memory at one time.

1 - Isn't `doall` supposed to be used with lazy sequences?

2 - I believe **reduce is not one**. Am I wrong?

3 - If `doall` should not be used with *reduce* in this case, what would be the recommendation for a refactoring here?

Comment: Also wouldn't hiccup just be fine with a lazy seq as i has to realzie it anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, `doall` only makes sense with lazy collections
2. `reduce` does not by itself create a lazy collection. But the reducing function (the first argument to `reduce`) might end up returning a lazy collection - in that case, `doall` might make sense
3. Impossible to say because the code that you've provided is incomplete and the parentheses are unbalanced

Comment: I bet you the function passed to reduce uses `concat`, which is why the author used `doall` at the end. This is a bandaid that doesn't really fix the problem at all.